# How to get a particular key value in a list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, json

Hello there this is my first stackoverflow question please bear with me.

my JSON file looks like this:

```
{"users":
 [
  {"name": "John Smith",
   "phone_num":"+104484932"
  },
  {"name": "Linda Ray",
   "phone_num": "+194387282"
  }
 ]
}
```

when given an input the script should look for the name in this list of dictionaries and return the phone number, I have tried many resources, it might also look like a possible copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541701/return-values-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-json-file) question.

Which it isn't, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `print([i[input_goes_here] for i in json['users'] if input_goes_here in i][0])`

Comment: @GhostOps shouldn't it be `i['phone_number']` instead of `i[input]`. Input could be any number and it might crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the json file into a python dict, then iterate over the `users` list.

```
def myfunction(target_name):
    with open('file.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for user in data['users']:
            if user['name'] == target_name:
                return user['phone_num']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted it to do :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way like

```py
json = {"users":
 [
  {"name": "John Smith",
   "phone_num":"+104484932"
  },
  {"name": "Linda Ray",
   "phone_num": "+194387282"
  }
 ]
}

inp = input('Name: ')

print([i['phone_num'] for i in json['users'] if i['name'] == inp][0])
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I already have an accepted answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

We don't have access to your code, so not sure what approach you are taking. Gonna presume that this is simple and barebones.

If the file is json, it will need to be read in and that will require that we import the `json` library.

```
import json
```

The question implies we are getting input directly from the user, so we can use the `input()` function to gather that data. Here we are providing a prompt that will display on the screen when the script is run.

```
username = input("Please supply a name: ")
```

From there, we read in the `json` file which gets read in as a Python dictionary. Since it is a dictionary (Python `dict()`), we can drill down into it to get to the data we care about querying on specific `keys` to see the associated `values`.

When we `open()` the file and I am choosing to refer to the opened file as `fin`. Then we pull out the content that is stored under the `users` key (that value happens to be a `list` of people).

```
with open('filename.json') as fin:
    book = json.load(fin)
    users = data['users']
```

Then we parse each user in the users list and check for matches to the `username` that was input earlier. When it finds a match, it prints the corresponding phone number.

```
    for user in users:
        if user['name'] == username:
            print(user['phone_num'])
```

The script in total will look something like this:

```
import json

username = input("Please supply a name: ")

with open('filename.json') as fin:
    book = json.load(fin)
    users = data['users']

    for user in users:
        if user['name'] == username:
            print(user['phone_num'])
```

Comment: This works too!